# Setting up Filezilla with gvim editor

Tags: vim, editor, gvim, filezilla

I want to edit ftp files from filezilla, with gvim

i open options > associated File types in Filezilla  and i have =

```
. /usr/bin/gedit
thtml /usr/bin/gedit
php /usr/bin/gedit
```

so i should replace by =

```
. /usr/bin/vim.gnome
thtml /usr/bin/vim.gnome
php /usr/bin/vim.gnome
html /usr/bin/vim.gnome
```

is it correct?

Comment: ... Well, I suppose that should work... But why not just make a backup of the old file and try, and just ask here when it seems that it actually *doesn't* work, in stead of just asking "Does this work?"?

Comment: Oh sorry, actually i have try this solution but it didnt work. When i want to edit the file, nothing happen.

Comment: Wait... You mean you just can't edit it? In the way of "When I type something, it doesn't appear on the screen!"?

Comment: it seem vim.gnome is not the correct way to call the gvim editor. Cause after editing options, i cannnot edit a file from a ftp.

Comment: I appreciate too :
[Open file from filezilla to gvim in a new tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21721953/open-file-from-filezilla-to-gvim-in-a-new-tab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
. /usr/bin/vi
thtml /usr/bin/vi
php /usr/bin/vi
html /usr/bin/vi
```

or

```
. /usr/bin/vim.tiny
thtml /usr/bin/vim.tiny
php /usr/bin/vim.tiny
html /usr/bin/vim.tiny
```

--Edit--
Well, as VIM is complaining that it needs a terminal window to be able to start, a solution would be to use the non-command-line version of VIM. Namely, *gvim*.

```
sudo aptitude install gvim
```

And this should be the file association configuration for FileZilla (tested it, and it worked for me):

```
. /usr/bin/gvim
thtml /usr/bin/gvim
php /usr/bin/gvim
html /usr/bin/gvim
```

Comment: hmmm didnt work for me, it seems filezilla can only execute gegit.

Comment: Aha! Found the problem :p I opened FileZilal from a terminal window to see what went wrong, and this is what I got:

> Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal
> Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal

I'll edit my answer with the solution.

Comment: Huh, the "solution" doesn't work after all xD FileZilla is being annoying here -.- Anyway, VI is a program that needs to be run in a terminal window, so iy complained about that. So I though using "xterm vi <file>" would work. Well, it did when I ran it from a terminal window, but not from FileZilla. Haven't given up yet though, I'm looking into it.

Comment: Ok, finally found a working solution xD